# Theorem 19.3 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $A_{\alpha}$ be a subspace of $X_{\alpha}$ , for each $\alpha \in J$. Then $\prod A_{\alpha}$ is a subspace of $\prod X_{\alpha}$ if both products are given the box topology, or if both products are given the product topology.

**My attempt:** what I done is that I have shown basis for subspace topology on $\prod A_\alpha$ inherent from $\prod X_\alpha$ is equal to basis for box/product topology on $\prod A_\alpha$. **Is this approach correct?**

Comment: **No**, the subspace topologies are very different in general, so you cannot show them to be equal.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma did I then proved something wrong?

Comment: Probably, yes....

Comment: I have checked by proof multiple times I don’t know where I’m wrong(I wish you’re wrong, I’m kidding). Here’s what I have shown, $\mathcal{B}=\{ (\prod A_\alpha )\cap U| U\in \mathcal{B}^\prime \}$, where $\mathcal{B}^\prime =\{ \prod R_\alpha |R_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}_{X_\alpha }\}$ basis of box topology. $\mathcal{B}_b =\{ \prod V_\alpha |V_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}_{A_\alpha }, \forall \alpha \}$. I have shown $\mathcal{B}= \mathcal{B}_b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your approach is right. It is justified by the Lemma 13.1 of Munkres that the two topologies are the same when they have same basis.

Comment: Or you may use Lemma 13.3.

Comment: Yeah. They(lemma 13.1, 13.3) are all very closely related. Why Henno Brandsma disagreeing with this approach?

Comment: Actually I don't understand his point. As far as I know, In this case the bases are same, and your approach is true.

Comment: Thank you for verifying my attempt.